# Default Navigation speed in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can the default navigation speed be changed in the Forge Viewer? The default setting is far to fast for my sample models. I should like to write code so that the speed may be changed during a session.

Comment: Hi, the (Pan, Walk, Zoom) speed of the navigation are set by the private variables userlookspeed, userZoomSpeed, userPanSpeed in viewer3d.js. while it seems there is not a set method, or a chance to override the releted functions. I am afriad if connecting the model on Forge (connecting to the on-line viewer3d.js), it might not be possible to change the speed. While if your web application has downloaded the off-line model data to your server (that means, a local viewer3d.js will be provided on your server), then you could try to modify those variables of the 'local' viewer3d.js

Comment: Hi, I am double confirmed by our engineer team that the First Person tool's current implementation doesn't allow to override those values. While you could try to hold SHIFT key when navigation. It would make it a bit slower.

Answer (score 2):

Copy an existing navigation tool from the viewer3D.js implementation, modify the speed parameters as you wish or expose methods to do so dynamically from your app, then set it active.

You can check the implementation of OrbitDollyPanTool L#14545 in viewer3D.js

```
Autodesk.Viewing.OrbitDollyPanTool = function( viewerImpl, viewerApi ){
    var avp = Autodesk.Viewing.Private;
    var _this = this;
    var kScreenEpsilon = 0.001;
    var kEpsilon = 0.00001;
    var kAutoDeltaZ  = 1.5;         // Dolly increment
    var kAutoDeltaXY = 0.01;
    var kAutoScreenXY = 20;
    var kDollyDragScale = 100.0;
    var kDollyPinchScale = 0.5;
    var kOrbitScale = 2.0;

    // ...
```

That tool is instantiated as follow (L#40923):

```
Viewer3D.prototype.createControls = function( ) {
    var self = this;
    var impl = self.impl;

    self.navigation = new av.Navigation(impl.camera);
    self.__initAutoCam(impl);

    self.utilities = new av.ViewingUtilities(impl, self.autocam, self.navigation);
    self.clickHandler = new av.DefaultHandler(impl, self.navigation, self.utilities);
    self.toolController = new av.ToolController(impl, self, self.autocam, self.utilities, self.clickHandler);
    self.toolController.registerTool( new av.GestureHandler(self) );

    self.toolController.registerTool( av.theHotkeyManager );
    self.toolController.activateTool( av.theHotkeyManager.getName() );

    self.registerUniversalHotkeys();

    self.toolController.registerTool( new av.OrbitDollyPanTool(impl, self) );
    self.toolController.activateTool( "gestures" );

    return self.toolController;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out that you can use `viewer.navigation.fitBounds(true, THREE.Box3)` which will impact the navigation speed to match the extends defined by those bounds.