# How to solve flickering issue of custom mesh

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have added custom mesh in sceneAfter but the problem is for 'Front Viewport'  we cant see mesh, so can anyone have solution for this [autodesk-forge]

Comment: Can you post code, indicate your browser version or set up a live environment on codepen/jsbin so we can reproduce the issue? Did you follow [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/custom-transparent-meshes-with-view-data-api.html) to put your code together?

Comment: @BryanHuang My issue is similar to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881921/setting-visible-bounds-in-forge-viewer?rq=1  but I cant use clone or trival mesh in scene