# Best way to add skybox to Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to add a skybox to a model in Forge Viewer. 
So far I have managed to create and add the skybox to the model via an extension.
The problem is that the skybox needs to be big, and the camera back clip plane will be to short; - eg. the skybox is only partially visible or hidden.

I did not manage to modify the camera settings to change the clip plane and was therefore thinking of another way:

I was wondering if it was better to keep the skybox in a separate ThreeJS Scene, but so far I am not able to figure out how the extra scene should be added to Autodesks Viewer3D, neither how it should be kept in sync with the main cameras rotation.

Any pointers and examples would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Loading an extra scene can be an overkill to achieve such feature, the easiest workaround would be load a second model that has a slightly larger extends than your skybox, so the viewer will automatically update its clippings plane.

What I suggest you to do is to translate a model that contains only tiny spheres or cubes defining the desired extends of the skybox scene. Then you will load that model either using its urn or downloading its resources and loading it "Local" even if your other model is loaded from the cloud.

See there for more details about extracting viewable resources and running Local vs cloud based:

[https://extract.autodesk.io](https://extract.autodesk.io/)

[Working seamlessly online/offline when developing your Web applications with the Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/working-seamlessly-onlineoffline-when-developing-apps-with-the-forge-viewer-.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: I have now added the model (a box in each 8 corners) locally, and you are right, the viewer does update the clipping plane and the model looks good. The drawback is that the first person view speed is affected and it is now not possible to reduce the speed enough to navigate good in the small model within the large skybox. Yes, I know the +,- and 0 for adjusting the speed, but it is not possible to get it slow enough. Any ideas?

Comment: You could copy the code of the existing navigation tool and customize it to your need, exposing a method that can set a different zoom factor speed for example. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671741/default-navigation-speed-in-forge-viewer